# First Image in Wordpress Post Will Not Center

Tags: wordpress, image, css-float, centering

In some of my posts (not all of them), the first image keeps floating right event though I have put in `<center></center>` tags. Can someone help me figure out why this is happening. Example here: http://renegadechicks.com/twelve-inspiring-centerpieces-3

Below is my CSS:

```
/*
Theme Name: StyleWeekly
Theme URI: http://cloverthemes.com/
Author: http://cloverthemes.com/
Author URI: http://cloverthemes.com/
Description: Style Weekly
Version: 1.2

Tags: magazine, beauty, style, fashion
*/

/* =Reset default browser CSS. Based on work by Eric Meyer: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/index.html
-------------------------------webs------------------------------- */

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pbackgre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, font, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, sub, sup, tt, var,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section,fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, br {
    border: 0;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-weight: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

:focus { /* remember to define focus styles! */ 
    outline: 0;
}

body {
    line-height: 1;
}

ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}

table { /* tables still need 'cellspacing="0"' in the markup */
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

caption, th, td {
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: left;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: "";
}

blockquote, q {
    quotes: "" "";
}

a img {
    border:5px solid #FBDDDF;
}

img.centered, .aligncenter, div.aligncenter {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    }

img.alignright {
    padding: 4px;
    margin: 0 0 2px 7px;
    display: inline;
    }

img.alignleft {
    padding: 4px;im
    margin: 0 7px 2px 0;
    display: inline;
    }

.alignright {
    float: right;
    }

.alignleft {
    float: left;
    }

.box img { display: block; margin: auto; }

img {
   display: block;
   width: auto;
   margin: auto;
}


small {font-size:11px;}
/* Floating 
---------------------------------------------------------------- */
.alignleft {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}
.alignright {
    float: right;
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
}
.aligncenter {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto 10px;
}
.left{float:left;}
.right{float:right;}

/* Clear Floats 
---------------------------------------------------------------- */
.clearfix:after { visibility: hidden; display: block; font-size: 0; content: " "; clear: both; height: 0; }
* html .clearfix             { zoom: 1; } /* IE6 */
*:first-child+html .clearfix { zoom: 1; } /* IE7 */

/* Global
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
body {
    color: #444;
    font-family: "Segoe UI","Helvetica","Arial",sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5em; 
    background: #000 url("images/graphicBg.jpg") no-repeat top center;
}

#inner {
background-color: #fff;
border: 3px solid #F10C6A;
padding: 20px}


#logos {
     display:none;
}

#linkwithin_logo_0 {
        display: none;
        padding-below: 5px;
}

#post-131 .st_facebook_large, #post-131 .st_twitter_large, #post-131 .st_pinterest_large, #post-131 .st_linkedin_large, #post-131 .st_email_large, #post-131 .st_sharethis_large, #post-131 .st_fblike_large {display: none;}

.stMainServices st-facebook-counter {
        padding-bottom:15px;
}

.c-1 {
float: left; padding-top: 20px;width:650px}

.c-1 .bd {
background: none}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {color:#cc0066; font-weight: normal;font-family:Georgia,"Times New Roman",Times,serif; padding-bottom: 10px;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 40px;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 30px;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 30px; padding-top: 5px;
}

h4 {
    font-size: 30px;
}

h5,h6 {
    font-size: 30px;
}

pre,code,kbd,samp,tt {mos
    font: 16px/1.385 "Courier New", Monospace, serif;
}


/* Hyperlinks
------------------------------------------------------------ */
a,
a:visited {
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a img {
    border: 5px solid #FBDDDF;
}

.imagelogo {
    border:none;
}


h1 a,h2 a,h3 a,h4 a, h5 a, h6 a {
    text-decoration: none; color: #
}

h1 a:hover,h2 a:hover,h3 a:hover,h4 a:hover,h5 a:hover,h6 a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline; color: #0AC6F5;
}

/* Input Form & TextArea 
---------------------------------------------------------------- */
input, textarea {
    border-color: #ccc #efefef #efefef #ccc;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    color: #777;
    padding: 6px;
}

input:focus {
    background: #ffffff;
}

/* Color
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
a,
a:visited, #logo .site-title a {
    color: #cc0066;border:none !important;
}

#nav, #nav li li a, #nav li li a:link, #nav li li a:visited{ text-transform:uppercase; }

.home-columns h3, .home-columns h4, a:hover {color: #0AC6F5;}

.home-columns a {text-decoration:none;}

#nav li a {color:#000000;}

#nav li a:hover {        
color:#0AC6F5;
}
#nav li li a:hover, #nav li li a:active{background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);text-transform: uppercase;}

#nav li li a, #nav li li a:link, #nav li li a:visited {
}

#nav { }


#nav ul li{ }
#nav ul li a { 
color: #fff}

#nav ul li ul li,#nav ul li ul li a  {
    border: none;
}

/* Padding
---------------------------------------------------------------- */
.pl20{padding-left:20px;}
.pl10{padding-left:10px;}
.pb10{padding-bottom:10px;}
.pb20{padding-bottom:20px;}
.pr20{padding-right:20px;}
.bd{background: url("images/dot.png") repeat-x scroll left bottom transparent;}
/* Header
---------------------------------------------------------------- */
#header {

}
#header .wrap {
    /*background: url("images/topbanner.png") no-repeat scroll 350px 43px transparent;*/
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    width:1012px;
    padding: 40px 0 20px 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
#logo h1, h1{
    font-size: 35px;
    line-height: 40px;
}   
#logo {
    float:left;
}

#logo .site-title a , .site-title a{
    color: #009999;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: "Georgia";
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 48px;
    line-height: 50px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 380px;
}

#logo .site-title a:hover  {
    text-decoration:none;
}

#description {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 0;
}



#header-right{
    padding: 0px 0 0;
    float:right;
    width:270px;
    }


/* Nav
---------------------------------------------------------------- */
#nav{border-bottom-style: inherit;height: 36px; text-transform: uppercase; width:1012px;
}
.menu-main-container, .menu{margin:0 auto; }
#nav li a .sf-sub-indicator{
    width: 11px;
    height: 32px;
    top: 18px;
    right: 0px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}
#nav li a:hover .sf-sub-indicator{
}
#nav li li a .sf-sub-indicator {
    top: 12px;
}   
#nav ul {   
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
}
#nav .sub-menu {
}
#nav .sub-menu .sub-menu{
    background: transparent !important;
}
#nav li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}


#nav li a {
    display: block;
    font-family: Helvetica,sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 11px 19px;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#nav .current-menu-item a {
}
#nav li a:hover, #nav li a:active {
}

#nav li li a, #nav li li a:link, #nav li li a:visited {
    font-size:12px;
    line-height: 20px;
    width: 132px; 
    margin: 0;
    padding:7px 21px 7px 13px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    position: relative;
}

#nav li li a:hover, #nav li li a:active {color:#fff;
}

#nav li ul {
    z-index: 9999;
    position: absolute;
    left: -999em;
    height: auto;
    width: 166px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
        background:#c06;
        text-transform:uppercase;
}

#nav li ul ul {
    margin: -35px 0 0 166px;
}

#nav li:hover ul ul, #nav li:hover ul ul ul, #nav li.sfHover ul ul, #nav li.sfHover ul ul ul {
    left: -999em;
}

#nav li:hover ul, #nav li li:hover ul, #nav li li li:hover ul, #nav li.sfHover ul, #nav li li.sfHover ul, #nav li li li.sfHover ul {
    left: auto;
}

#nav li:hover, #nav li.sfHover { 
    position: static;
}

#nav li a span {
    color:#999;
    display: block;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 14px;
}

/* Main
---------------------------------------------------------------- */
#wrapper{margin:0 auto; width:1012px; padding:0px;}h2
#home-third-left{width:660px;}
#home-sidebar{width:300px; float:right;}

#content-sidebar{width:980px;}
#content{width:660px; float:left; min-height:600px;}

/* Homepage Elements
---------------------------------------------------------------- */
#home-top .a-left ul{margin-left:-3px;}
#home-top .a-left li{float:left; padding-left:4px;}
#home-second h3{font-size:32px;}
#home-top .entry-excerpt p{font-size:13px; font-family:Georgia,"Times New Roman",Times,serif; line-height:22px;width:205px;float:left}
#home-top {padding-bottom: 36px;}

.a-left h3 {padding:10px 0px 10px 0px;font-family: 'Cookie', cursive;}
.a-left h3 a{color:#000000; font-size:45px;}
.a-left{padding-bottom: 5px;}
.a-left{width:660px;}
.a-right p{padding:0 40px 10px 10px;}
.a-right{width:300px; }

.home-post{padding-bottom:15px;margin-bottom:20px; min-height: 135px !important;font-size: 13px;line-height: 22px;}

.home-category {
float:left;
width:635px;
}

.home-category h2{font-size:40px;padding-bottom:20px;}
.small{font-size:10px; color:#999;}
.b-1{width:638px; float:left; padding-right: 4px;padding-top: 25px;}
.b-2{width:400px; float:left;}
.firstpost{padding-bottom:10px;margin-bottom:5px;}
.firstpost .entry-excerpt {font-size: 13px;line-height: 22px}
.b-3{width:445px;float:right; /*font-size:11px; line-height:18px;*/}

.b-1 h3 {line-height:28px;}

.c-1-post {width:200px; margin-left: 20px;margin-bottom:5px}
.c-1 h3{font-size:13px !important;padding-top:5px !important;line-height:20px;padding-bottom: 0px !important;}

.c-2-1{width:260px;}
.c-2-1 h3, .c-2-2 h3, .c-3 h3, .d-1 h3{font-size:26px; padding-bottom:10px;}

.c-2-2{width:380px; }
.c-2-2-post{margin-bottom: 15px;min-height: 100px !important;padding-bottom: 15px;}
.c-2-2 p{line-height:22px;font-size:13px}

.c-3-left, .c-3-right{width:320px;}

.featured-left{float:left; width:320px;}

.block-small-item{
    height: 90px;
    margin-bottom: 13px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 13px; width:320px}

.block-meta {
    color: #888888;
    display: block;
    font-size: 11px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
}
.block-meta a {
    color: #888888 !important;
}
.block-meta a:hover {
    color: #333333 !important;
    text-decoration: none;
}


/* Post Page Style
---------------------------------------------------------------- */
.breadcrumbs {background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F6F6F6;color: #666666;font-size: 11px;margin: 0 0 10px;padding: 3px 15px; display:none;}
.entry-content p{color: #464646;font-family: Georgia,Sans-serif; margin: 0 0 16px; line-height:24px; font-size: 13px;}

.entry-title{margin-bottom:13px;margin-top: 3px;background: url("images/dot.png") repeat-x  scroll left bottom transparent;}

.entry-title h1 { color: #000000!important; }

.entry-content h2, .entry-content h3{ font-size: 32px;}

.entry-content ol, .entry-content ul {margin: 0;padding: 0 0 20px;}

.entry-content ol {margin: 0;}

.entry-content ul li {list-style-type: square;margin: 0 0 0 10px;}

.entry-content ol li {list-style: decimal outside none;margin: 0 0 0 25px;}

.entry-content ol ol, .entry-content ul ul {padding: 0;}

.entry-content li{padding:0 0 5px 0;}
.entry-content .wp-caption-text{color: #666666;font-size: 11px;font-style: italic;line-height: 16px;margin: 0;text-align: center;}
.post-meta {
    background-color: #F6f6f6;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    clear: both;
    color: #666666;
    font-size: 11px;
    padding: 7px 10px 5px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    display: none;
}

.entry-content clearfix {
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.post-info {
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    font-family: verdana;
    color: black;
}

.linkwithin_posts a {
    background: none !important;
    border: none !important;
    padding-right: 5px !important;
}

.linkwithin_hook {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    color: #;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: -0.25px;
    line-height: 45px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.linkwithin_text {
    color: #cc0066;
    font-size: 38px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.linkwithin_title {
    color: #464646!important;
    font-family: verdana, sans-serif !important;
    font-size: 12px !important;
    line-height: 14px !important;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.linkwithin_title:hover {
    color: #c06!important;
    text-decoration: underline !important;
}


.post-info .post-author {
      background: url("images/post-author.png") no-repeat scroll left center transparent;
      padding: 5px 16px 3px 61px;
      font-size: 12px;
      font-style: italic;
}
.post-info .time {
    font-style:italic;

}en
.post-comments {
    background: url("images/post-comments.png") no-repeat scroll left center transparent;
    padding: 6px 20px 6px 40px;
}

#disqus_thread {
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.cat{
    background: url("images/icon-categories.png") no-repeat scroll left top transparent;
    padding: 3px 0 3px 22px; display: none;
    }

.tags{
    background: url("images/icon-tags.png") no-repeat scroll left top transparent;
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
    padding: 3px 0 3px 20px; display: none;
    }   
blockquote {background: url(images/q.png) no-repeat;border: none;margin: 5px 15px;padding: 15px 20px 10px 40px;}

blockquote p {color: #666;font-style: italic;}

.page-template-page-fullwidth-php #content{width:980px;}


#social{width:660px; padding:10px 0 5px; display:none;}

/* Pre- Next
---------------------------------------------------------------- */ 
#nav-below {padding-bottom:20px;}
.nav-previous a, .nav-next a {background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #0197B2;color: #FFFFFF;float: left;width: 100px;
    font-weight: bold;display: block;font-size:12px;line-height:26px;font-family:arial,verdana,sans-serif;
    height: 25px;text-align: center;width: 80px;overflow: hidden;}

.nav-previous a:hover, .nav-next a:hover{background:#009999;}
#nav-below .nav-previous a, #nav-below .nav-next a {
    padding: 0 10px;
    width: 45%;
}
.nav-previous a {
    float: right;
}
.nav-next a {
    float: left;
}
.nav-next a:hover, .nav-previous a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Related Posts
---------------------------------------------------------------- */
.related-posts{  font-size:12px; line-height:18px;}
.relateimage img {border: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;}

.listing {float: left;
    padding-left: 20px; 
    width: 150px; }
.related-posts-title {
    color: #0091A8;
    margin:20px 0 10px 22px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;}

/* Sidebar
---------------------------------------------------------------- */
#sidebar{
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    line-height: 20px;
    width: 300px;
}

#sidebar h4, #latest-posts h4 {
    /*background-color: #0AC6F5;*/
    background: url("images/banner.jpg") no-repeat top center;
    color: #fff;
        font-size: 36px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height: 38px;
    padding: 7px 0px 0px 3px;
    margin: 0 0 5px;
}
#sidebar p{margin-bottom:10px;}
.widget-wrap {
    margin: 0 0 10px;
}

.widget{
    margin: 0 0 30px;
}

.widget-area ul li {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #CCCCCC;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0 0 5px 5px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
font-size: 13px;
}

.widget-area  li  li, .widget-area li li li{
    border-bottom: 0 none;
    list-style: square outside none;
    margin: 0 0 0 20px;
    padding: 5px 0 0 0;
}

#sidebar .flickr-photos  li{
    float: left;
    background:none;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding:8px;
}


#sidebar .twitter h4{
    background: url("images/tt.png") no-repeat scroll left center transparent;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding: 0 0 0 40px;
}

#sidebar_left{
    float: left;
    width:160px;

#sidebar_left a {
         text-decoration:none !important;}
}

a:-webkit-any-link {
         text-decoration:none !important;}
}

#header-right a:-webkit-any-link {
        padding-right: 15px;
}

#sidebar_right{
    float: right;
    width:120px;
}

.twitter h4 {
    background: url("images/tt.png") no-repeat scroll left center transparent;
    padding: 0 0 6px 35px;}

/* archive
---------------------------------------------------------------- */
.archive .post img, .search .post img {width:150px; height:auto;}
#archive-title {padding-bottom:15px; font-size:22px; display:none;}

/* search
---------------------------------------------------------------- */
input[type="button"], input[type="submit"] { border: none;color: #FFFFFF;cursor: pointer;font-size: 13px;font-weight: normal;text-decoration: none; }

input[type="button"]:hover, input[type="submit"]:hover {background-color: #565656; }

input, select, textarea,.sticky, .taxonomy-description {border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;}

#search {width: 265px;
padding-left: 18px;
padding-top: 5px;
padding-bottom: 10px;}

#search .s {
    background: #c06;
    border: medium none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 5px 8px;
    width: 157px;float: left;
}

#search .search-submit{background: url("images/s.png") no-repeat scroll center center transparent;
    border: medium none;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    height: 28px;
    margin: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 39px;}

#search div {
    background: #c06;
    height: 27px;
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid #0AC6F5;
}




/* Pagination
---------------------------------------------------------------- */
.ct-paginate {padding: 10px 0 20px 0; overflow:hidden; clear:both; font-family: arial;}
.ct-paginate a {border:1px solid #eee;  margin-right:5px; padding:4px 8px; text-align:center; text-decoration:none;}
.ct-paginate .ct-title {color:#555; margin-right:4px;}
.ct-paginate .ct-gap {color:#999; margin-right:4px;}
.ct-paginate a:hover, .ct-paginate a:active, .ct-paginate .ct-current {color:#fff; background: url("images/navbg.png") repeat scroll 0 0 #333333;border:1px solid #ddd; margin-right:5px;padding:4px 8px;}


/* Footer
---------------------------------------------------------------- */
.footer-info {padding:30px 0;}
.footer-info .right{width:1012px;text-align:center;}

/* =Comments
------------------------------------------------------------------ */
#comments {padding:20px 0 0 0;}
#comments h3,#respond h4{color: #0091A8;
}
#comments a{
    text-decoration:none;
}
#comments a:hover{
    text-decoration:underline;
}

#comments input:hover, #commentstextarea:hover{
    background: #f5f5f5;
}
#commentform {
    margin: 5px 10px 0px 0px;
}

#commentform textarea {
    width: 90%;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size:13px
}

#respond:after {
    content: "."; 
    display: block; 
    height: 0px; 
    clear: both; 
    visibility: hidden;
}

#commentform p {
    margin: 20px 0;
}



#commentform #submit, .wpcf7-submit{
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #fbafe3;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #fbafe3;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #fbafe3;
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #f03c96), color-stop(1, #cc0066) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #f03c96 5%, #cc0066 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#f03c96', endColorstr='#cc0066');
    background-color:#f03c96;
    -moz-border-radius:17px;
    -webkit-border-radius:17px;
    border-radius:17px;
    border:1px solid #ee1eb5;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:13px;
    padding:6px 24px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #ff0080;
}
#commentform #submit:hover, .wpcf7-submit:hover {
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ef027d), color-stop(1, #ff5bb0) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #ef027d 5%, #ff5bb0 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ef027d', endColorstr='#ff5bb0');
    background-color:#ef027d;
}
#commentform #submit:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}


.commentlist {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.commentlist ol {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.commentlist li {
    margin: 15px 0;
    padding:15px;
    list-style: none;
}
.commentlist li ul li { 
    margin: 10px;
}

.commentlist p {
    margin: 10px 5px 10px 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.commentlist li ul li {
    font-size: 12px;
}


.commentlist li .avatar { 
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    padding: 3px;
}

.commentlist cite, .commentlist cite a {
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.commentlist p {
}

.commentmetadata {
    font-weight: normal;
    padding:5px 0 0 0;
}

.alt {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.children { 
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.nocomments {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.commentmetadata {
    font-size: 11px;
    margin: 0px;
    display: block;
}

.navigation {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}


.thread-alt {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.thread-even {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.depth-1 {
    border: 1px solid #BBBBBB;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.even, .alt {
    border:1px solid #eeeeee;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
em.date, .comment strong {
    font-weight:normal;
    color:#9E825F;
    line-height:24px;
    display:block;
    font-style: normal;
} 

/* Socialmedia
---------------------------------------------------------------- */ 

/* Additional
---------------------------------------------------------------- */

/* Styling posts
---------------------------------------------------------------- */

.one_half, .one_third, .two_third, .three_fourth, .one_fourth {
    float: left;
    line-height: 21px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-right: 4%;
}
.one_half {
    width: 48%;
}
.one_third {
    width: 30.6%;
}
.two_third {
    width: 65.3%;
}
.one_fourth {
    width: 22%;
}
.three_fourth {
    width: 74%;
}
.last {
    clear: right;
    margin-right: 0 !important;
}

.dropcap {
    color: #383838;
    float: left;
    font-size: 40px;
    margin-right: 6px;
    padding-top: 7px;
    position: relative;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    top: 5px;
}

.highlight1 {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F6F67A;
}
.highlight2 {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000000;
    color: #CCCCCC;
}

.mosaic-block {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:210px;
    height:120px;
    /*background:#111 url(images/progress.gif) no-repeat center center;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);*/
        border-radius: 15px;
}

    .mosaic-backdrop {
        display:none;
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
        /*background:#111;*/
    }

    .mosaic-overlay {
        display:none;
        z-index:5;
        position:absolute;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        background:#111;
    }

.bar .mosaic-overlay {
            bottom:-100px;
            height:40px;
            background:url(images/bg-black.png);
        }
.details{ margin:3px 10px; color:#eee; font-size:11px;} 

.footer-links-copyright, .footer-links-copyright a{ color:#0AC6F5; font-size:11px;padding-right:10px;}
.attachment1{ text-align:center;}
#content .gallery img, #gallery-listing img{background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #DDDDDD;border: 5px solid #FFFFFF; box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #CCCCCC;margin: 5px; padding: 1px; max-width:160px; height:auto;}

#content .cb_pin_images {
margin-left: auto !important;
margin-right: auto !important;
}
.entry-content img {max-width:100%; height:auto; border: 5px solid #FBDDDF;}

.first-thumb img {
box-shadow:5px 5px 1px #888;}

.hfeed img.thumbnail {
    float: left; height: 160px;
        }

.archive .hfeed article {
    margin-left: 20px;
    float:left;
        width: 470px;}
    }
```

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried and provide a minimal(!) example at jsfiddle.net. Nobody's got the time to read and interpret your very long code paste.

Answer (score 1):

I changed this HTML for the first image

```
<center><a href="http://renegadechicks.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/centerpiece15.jpg
<img class="size-full wp-image-10673 aligncenter" alt="centerpiece15" src="http://renegadechicks.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/centerpiece15.jpg" width="361" height="559">
</a></center>
```

To this in chrome:

```
<p style="clear: both;">
<a href="http://renegadechicks.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/centerpiece15.jpg">
<img class="size-full wp-image-10673 aligncenter" alt="centerpiece15" src="http://renegadechicks.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/centerpiece15.jpg" width="361" height="559">
</a>
</p>
```

and it seemed to center just fine.  I for some reason had to toggle the text-decoration on the  tag off then on for it to work...

Basically, I replaced the < center > tags with < p> tags and made sure to clear any floats that were set up before hand.